# I Get PING FAILED Error Loading on My Server

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

When uploading videos to AWS on localhost, I can upload regardless of the size and it does not give an error.

But when I take these codes to the AWS server and try to upload a file over 100 MB, it gives this **error (failed)net::ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAILED**

Am I making a mistake somewhere, am I missing something or is there something I need to check?

```
return Plupload::file('file', function ($file) {
    try {
        $path = Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('medias', $file);
        $cmd = Storage::disk('s3')
            ->getDriver()
            ->getAdapter()
            ->getClient()
            ->getCommand('GetObject', [
                'Bucket' => config("filesystems.disks.s3.bucket"),
                'Key'    => $path,
            ]);
        $link = Storage::disk('s3')
            ->getDriver()
            ->getAdapter()
            ->getClient()
            ->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+12 hours')
            ->getUri();

         $linkSave=(string) $link;

        $token = config('services.cloudflare.token');
        $accountId = config('services.cloudflare.acountId');
        $client = new Client();
        //file upload
        /*
                        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/' . $accountId . '/stream', [
                            'headers' => [
                                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
                            ],
                            'multipart' => [
                                [
                                    'name' => 'file',
                                    'contents' => fopen($file, 'r+'),
                                    'filename' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                                ],
                            ]
                        ]);*/
        //link upload
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/' . $accountId . '/stream/copy', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'json' => [
                "url" => $linkSave,
                "meta" => [
                    "name" => $file->getClientOriginalName()
                ]
            ]

        ]);

        $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true); // returns an array
        $path = null;

        foreach ($data as $key => $dat) {
            if (is_array($dat) && array_key_exists('preview', $dat)) {
                $path = $dat['preview'];
            }
        }
        $videoUrl = str_replace('watch', 'iframe', $path);
        $videoPath = '<iframe src="' . $videoUrl . '" style="border: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;" allow="accelerometer; gyroscope; autoplay; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture;" allowfullscreen="true" id="stream-player"></iframe>';

        $media = Media::create([
            'name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
            'path' => $videoPath,
            'extension' => $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        ]);
        return [
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Upload successful.',
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Upload error.',
        ];
    }
```

I increased all the video upload and waiting limits in the PHP.ini file. but I still keep getting this error. I don't know how to get rid of this error.

Comment: 1. Could you share the configuration you set to connect to AWS?

Comment: 'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('/'),
        ],
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'AKIXD'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '1Amdja7m'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'eu-central-1'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET', 'edanisman'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ], Is this the place you wanted?

Comment: try removing 'url' =>  env('AWS_URL'), and re-try... your error means that the endpoint you're hitting is unpingable.

Comment: Thank you but it did not work :(